# Convert react reducer to typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm quite new to typescript and I was hoping someone could help me go about converting this typescript. I've done a quite a bit with typescript but I've never really touched reducers with TS.

this is what I'm working with:

````
export default function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      // return current state if empty
      if (!action.payload) {
        return state;
      }
      // return current state if duplicate
      if (state.includes(action.payload)) {
        return state;
      }
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999),
          title: action.payload,
          completed: false
        }
      ];
    case "EDIT_TODO":
      return state.map(todo => {
        return todo.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : todo;
      });
    case "DELETE_TODO":
      return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload);
    case "COMPLETE_TODO":
      return state.map(todo =>
        todo.id === action.payload```
          ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }
          : todo
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by defining the interfaces for your `todo` object, for `state` and for `action`.

Here's a starting point, there will likely be some syntax errors, some dues to typescript types needing changing, but also there are a few bugs in your reducer code that this will highlight so they need to be fixed too.

```
type Todo = {
    id: number,
    title: string
    completed: boolean,
}

type Action = {
    type: "ADD_TODO" | "EDIT_TODO" | "DELETE_TODO" | "COMPLETE_TODO",
    payload: Todo,
}

type State = Todo[]
```

You can also go further, and define the action strings as constants, so that you are using the same variable in the switch statement and the action type definition.

Redux also comes with helpers like `action: PayloadAction<number>` that automatically do some typing for you, you may or may not have success with that depending on how you've written your reducers.

Get more info from here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript